# How do I find out the composition factors of a group of order $165$?

Tags: group-theory

I've figured out that there is $1$ Sylow $p-$subgroup for $p=11$. I tried by taking the first factor in the composition series to be this subgroup, but I don't see how to determine the following factors. The number of Sylow $p-$subgroups for $p=3$ may be $1$ or $55$ and for $p=5$ may be $1$ or $11$. How do I find the different possibilities of the series without knowing further about the group? All I know is that the composition factors are simple.

Please see that I'm trying to find the various series, not accounting for isomorphisms and permutations. I know that the Jordan Holder theorem says that up to isomorphisms and permutations, the series is unique.